# How to share an instance variable among different classes in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a class `Game` with attributes `player1`, `player2`, and `Q`. `player1` and `player2` are themselves instances of the class `Player` which also has an attribute called `Q`. I would like to make it such that when I instantiate a `Game`, it shares its `Q` with the instances of `Player` it was instantiated with.

To illustrate what I mean, consider this code:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, player1, player2):
        self.player1 = player1
        self.player2 = player2
        self.Q = {}

class Player:
    def __init__(self, mark):
        self.mark = mark
        self.Q = {}

player1 = Player(mark="X")
player2 = Player(mark="O")

game = Game(player1, player2)           # Instantiate a game with player 1 and player 2

game.Q["some key"] = "some value"

# I would like this to happen automatically
player1.Q = game.Q
player2.Q = game.Q
```

I'd like `player1` and `player2`'s `Q` variable to get updated automatically to `game.Q` whenever it changes. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `self.Q = self.player1.Q = self.player2.Q = {}` in the constructor and you're done.

Comment: @Rawing: You might as well write that out as a full answer.

Comment: The content of q is somewhat vaguely described, but I guess,that in a well-structured solution the player instance should receive a reference to its game instead instead of duplicating member variables.

Comment: @guidot Fair call, although that does make accessing the dict a bit more tedious, since you have to do something like `player1.game.Q`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [Rawing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222951/rawing)'s comment, I used `self.Q = self.player1.Q = self.player2.Q = {}` in the `__init__` of `Game`:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, player1, player2):
        self.player1 = player1
        self.player2 = player2
        self.Q = self.player1.Q = self.player2.Q = {}

class Player:
    def __init__(self, mark):
        self.mark = mark
        self.Q = {}

player1 = Player(mark="X")
player2 = Player(mark="O")

game = Game(player1, player2)           # Instantiate a game with player 1 and player 2

game.Q["some key"] = "some value"
```

As a result, `player1.Q` now yields `{'some key': 'some value'}` without having to 'update' it manually.

Comment: Also set `self.Q = None` in your `Player` class.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto I wouldn't initialise `self.Q` in `Player.__init__` (either to an empty `dict` or to `None`). If you somehow attempt to access the `.Q` attribute of a `Player` instance before the player is connected with a `Game` instance it will fail noisily with an `AttributeError` exception. And if that happens you'll know you've got a defect in your code logic that you need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce base class with `Q` as a class attribute:

```
class Base(object):
    Q = {}


class Player(Base):
    def __init__(self, mark):
        self.mark = mark


class Game(Base):
    def __init__(self, player1, player2):
        self.player1 = player1
        self.player2 = player2


player1 = Player(mark="X")
player2 = Player(mark="O")

game = Game(player1, player2)           # Instantiate a game with player 1 and player 2

game.Q["some key"] = "some value"
```

But this works only if you want to have one instance of game with players because if you create next `Game` it will have same `Q` as the previous one.

Comment: It does, `Q` dict instance is shared across all class instances.

Comment: @guidot: They will be synchronized because they are all using the one Base.Q class attribute. The drawback, as Mateusz mentions, is that you can't create multiple Game instances with different Qs, but that may not be a problem in this application.